# mkdir multiple directories with a subdirectory name having space in it

Tags: bash, quoting, brace-expansion

I want to make multiple directories in one go. The problem is that one of the sub directories have a name with a space in it. The directory structure i want to make is as follows.

```
project
    /level 1
    /level2
```

I tried escaping the space but it does not seem to work. Here is my command.

```
mkdir -p project/{level\ 1,level2}
```

But this does not seem to work. and results in directory structure like.

```
project
    /level

1,level2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your .bashrc, because nothing wrongs with your command.

Comment: Those cmds works for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try`mkdir -p project/{'level 1','level 2'}`

Comment: This would also work: `mkdir -p project/level{' 1', 2}`